# Comment répartir un bounty entre plusieurs bonnes réponses

Tags: discussion

Pratiquement toutes les réponses à *[cette question](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/40593/848)* ont apporté un éclairage différent sur la question posée, et surtout elles ont participé avec leurs commentaires, peut-être même sans que leur auteur s’en rende compte, à son évolution positive.

Y a-t-il moyen de répartir la totalité des points engagés sur plusieurs réponses

---

***Réponse : non***, et en cas d’erreur, on ne peut même pas changer ledestinataire

Comment: Je ne sais pas exactement ce que les reponses au lien suivant veulent dire aujourd'hui, mais il y a 10 ans ce n'etait pas possible si je comprends bien. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2786/accept-multiple-answers-or-split-bounty-among-several-users

Comment: Cette question serait plus appropriée sur [meta stackexchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com)